# Allow 'improve' for Tag Wiki Edit Suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, improve-edit

I've been approving or rejecting Tag Wiki Excerpt Edit Suggestions, but some of them are close and I'd like to just tweak them.  We can **improve** regular edit suggestions, how about giving us an <kbd>Improve</kbd> button for Tag Wiki Edit Suggestions.

Note: If I click on the `tag wiki excerpt` link, then it takes me to a Tag Wiki page with an `edit pending` link, but clicking on that just takes me back to the first page, where I can only approve/reject.

Comment: I've wanted this too; I usually just open another browser tab for the tag and hope that the edits pass by the time I next stumble on the tab...

Comment: by design, we do not allow you to improve something you have no permission to edit.

Comment: @SamSaffron In that case the page shouldn't invite us to improve it! I found it confusing and spent much time trying to work out how to do what I'd been invited to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tag wiki edit suggestions can be `Improved`, same as other posts.

But you can only `Improve` a post if you would have the right to edit it unsupervised. For questions and answers, the requirement is the same as approving edits: [2000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit). For tag wikis, you can **approve at [5000](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)** reputation, but you need **[20000](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) to make your own** unsupervised edit. So as long as you're in the 5k-20k range, you can approve or reject tag wiki suggeted edits but not `Improve` them.

Ok, the system could be changed to allow you to suggest a second edit. But on Stack Overflow, where suggested edits require two approvers, that would be fairly complex:

1. User A comes along, suggests an edit.
2. User B improves the edit, suggests a second edit that depends on the first.
3. User C improves A and B's edits; or maybe approves A's and reject B's, or maybe decides that B's edit is great but A's stinks, ... The set of possibilities grows quickly.

Would the complexity it really be worth it? Can't you just approve or reject and wait a bit? Tag wikis don't require the edit fluidity of posts, a delay of a few hours won't hurt.

---

Complementary note for beta sites: the reputation requirements are 1000 for normal edits, 1500 to approve tag wikis, and 4000 to edit tag wikis without supervision.

Comment: Hmmm, I never realized the 20k limit, or the 5k one.  I though since you only needed 2500 to make a tag wiki, that that would be the number used for all those things.  I wonder why the big disconnect.

Comment: @Lance The tag wiki reputation requirements changed [last February](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446). The justification must be on Meta somewhere but I can't find where.

Comment: heheh, I didn't checked the feature before putting bounty, I can already see "Improve" button on Tag wiki, and its excerpt on SO.

Comment: I often see tag wiki texts, which are fresh suggestions, but with typos or gramer mistakes. Shall I approve them, because then they can be corrected, or shall I reject them? I approve, normally.

Answer (score 3):

What does not make much sense is being able to approve wiki edits at a lower reputation level than making an unsupervised edit. These two powers are closely related and should be granted at the same time, just like it is for regular posts. Whether is should happen at 5000, 20000 or some intermediate level doesn't matter much, but having them at different levels seems inconsistent, and introduces additional complexity as demonstrated in Gilles' post.

Not being able to improve a suggested wiki edit has bothered me several times. You have to approve, and come back later, which is very inconvenient.