# Approving tag wiki edits - reject based on a typo?

Tags: support

I've just gained the Approve Tag Wiki privilege on Stack Overflow and thought I'd do some approving/rejecting via the edit queue before the novelty wears off!

I noticed that on tag wikis my only options are to **Approve** or **Reject** and there is no **Improve** option as on 'standard' edits. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95520/allow-improve-for-tag-wiki-edit-suggestions) says that's by design.

This being the case, when I come across a suggested tag wiki which meets [the guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) and has good content, but contains a glaring typo (for example, *cumputer*), should I reject it - even though it's perfect except for the typo?

Answer (score 6):

Personally, if it's reasonably substantial, I'd approve it, then go and edit it myself to fix the typo. If someone has written some good content, it should be used, and they should get credit for it.

If, on the other hand, it's just a few words, and one or more are misspelled, well, I'd probably reject it; not worth the trouble to go and fix.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, like so many things in life, *it depends*.

For me, personally, if there was nothing there before and the content is otherwise decent, I'd approve it. For tag wikis, something is usually better than nothing.

Of course, in that case, I'd immediately jump on over and fix the errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could always leave it in the queue. 20k users can improve tag wiki edits, so you can hope one of *them* will see it in the queue and do the improving for you.

Otherwise *it depends*. If it's already got one approve vote, you can of course approve it and immediately submit the correction yourself. If there's *many* typos/ poor grammar, then reject it. If it's a substantial piece of work with only a few typos, I'd be inclined to accept it. Otherwise reject.

Comment: -1? ... jeez, that hurt.