# When reviewing suggested edits, show the number and/or reasons of rejected votes

Tags: feature-request, edits, review

(This question is similar to a [previous question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165379/proposed-methods-for-countering-plagiarized-text-in-tag-wikis), but that question was specific to tag wiki reviews, and the question has morphed and gone all chameleon since I last asked it)

When reviewing Suggested Edits, I would like to be able to see:

- the number of rejected votes against the current edit I am reviewing, as well as ....
- a list of all the reasons it has been rejected so far.

To me, each and every edit should **improve** a question or answer; if someone feels that the suggested edit should be rejected, I would like to know that when reviewing the edit.  This would be of especially great joy to me, since I feel I'm often the first to reject as "Copied Content", only to see the next three votes approve the edit.  Blah!

We've done a great job of blocking robo-approvers, and I think this would be a good next step to people who can spot review audits, but still approve questionable/minor/copied/just-plain-crap edits.

Comment: Often after I vote hit the back button, and see how others voted.

Comment: Not sure how I feel about this.  The votes of others shouldn't have any bearing of how I value this particular suggested edit.

Comment: I suggest to not enable this by default, because the reviewer may be biased if s/he can see existing reviews: knowing that an edit has been rejected twice, might encourage one to reject an edit as well.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, yes I get your point, just letting you know about that method in case you didn't.

Comment: At that point, I'd be convinced that the votes are biasing the person's opinion and honest feedback of the review.  Reviewing content isn't about what the *other* people think, it's whether or not the edit has any merit to it.

Comment: O_o How did you manage to dissociate this question from your account?

Answer (score 8):

- If seeing how others voted would change the way you vote, the request seems like a bad idea.
- If seeing how others voted wouldn't change the way you vote, the request seems pointless.

Swapping the positions of *you* and *others* doesn't change anything.

From your question I understand that you want to be able to communicate your reason for rejecting to others so that they don't miss what you see. That's just another angle on influencing votes, but perhaps it's a legitimate kind of influence. A point in your favor is that we already have this for close votes. If one is okay and not the other, we should have a clear understanding of why that is.

Comment: Close votes aren't treated that differently if you are going through the review queue. The main review screen does not show you how many votes have been cast, it asks for action first. You can see those numbers if you open the question directly or if you choose to close and then count up the reasons people have gone with, but the principle is still calling for action without a number to influence you. By the same token you can see suggested edits and find the review status elsewhere if you look too, but when actually doing reviews, it shouldn't be a main factor so it isn't shown.

Answer (score 2):

If we get to know if the edit has been rejected by someone else earlier it can influence our judgement of the edit. So, its generally a bad thing to show on the face of the edit if it has been accepted/rejected earlier by another reviewer.

However, there is still a way to know if the edit has been rejected earlier by another reviewer. When you hit the **Reject** button, it pops a dialog box. And if the edit has been rejected using one of the pre-defined reject reasons, it shows the number beside it to indicate that. However, if the edit is rejected using a **Custom** reject reason, you don't get to see the reasoning of the other reviewers till you have reviewed it yourself, but it still shows the number beside Custom to indicate how many reviewers used the Custom reason to reject the edit. As you can see in the image below, it shows that the edit has been earlier rejected by another reviewer as an **invalid edit**.

> [image: rejected edit]

Moreover, as others have noted, you may hit the back button in your browser to go to that edit and see its fate after you have reviewed it.

You may also navigate to the **History** tab which lists all the edits that you have reviewed to see the opinion of other reviewers about the edit.

> [image: history tab]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a good idea since it might influence how we vote.  I think it helps the system to have everyone cast separate uninfluenced votes.  In the end, if I'm not sure, then I just Skip it.

Note that after you vote, you can hit the back button, and see how others voted.

Comment: Yes, it does appear that Close Votes influence more to vote to close.  Not sure where to draw the line here.  It would probably work better if when rejecting more specific reasons would be given, but the time that would take would probably hose he review process.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables We *don't* show the number of close votes in the *Close Votes* review. And we *don't* show the number of delete votes on the *Low Quality Posts* review. No inconsistency there.