# Combat plagiarism in suggested edits by alerting subsequent reviewers

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, plagiarism

I've been rejecting my fair share of plagiarized suggested edits, mostly tag wiki edits, on my two beta sites I'm involved in.

Here's the thing: It's *way* to easy for them to get through. For one to get through, all we need is two (three on SO) reviewers on the post that don't bother to punch the edit into Google in quotes - something I'm certainly guilty of not doing.

What if we could have the system alert subsequent reviewers to the problem after a reviewer rejected the edit as plagiarism? Then, only *one* person would have to do the long, back-breaking task of punching it into Google.

Here's what I'm thinking:

When I go to reject an edit, add a text field to the **copied content** reason, a place to indicate *where* the content was copied from:

[image]

Since we now have this information, we can show it to subsequent reviewers - along with a big red alert bubble:

[image]

The link would be clickable, opening a new tab with the allegedly-copied-from website. Then, I, as the subsequent reviewer, would be instantly alerted to the potential problem - allowing us to have a better filter for plagiarism.

I realize it's a big change - it would probably have a slight hit on performance. But it would have a *huge* hit on the amount of plagiarism that gets through - making the internet a better place.

Comment: Posted as answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/201884/215468