# Suggested edit review instructions mistakenly indicate that 5k+ users can improve tag wiki suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I was looking through some suggested edits and saw some for tag wikis, and one needed a small but pertinent change. The instructions initially indicate that this is possible, but then offer no edit choice, either in the list of actions:

> Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users.
>
> - Approve edits that clearly improve the post
> - Reject edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse
> - Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

or as one of the edit buttons:

[image]

I see that a Trusted User has the privilege of "Editing tag wikis without needing approval," and I am not at that level yet, but the way it is currently worded, it seems that I should be able to improve a suggested wiki edit and then vote to approve it with my additional input.
As it stands, I have only the choice to **Approve** the edit (which has one or more issues), or **Reject** the edit (which is a clear improvement over what was there previously).

I'd suggest that we either

1. Change the wording from the blockquote above to read

   > Approve or reject edits suggested by users.

   or
2. Add another button similar to one that is seen when approving question/answer edits, allowing the reviewer to "Improve this edit."

Personally, I'd vote for choice number 2.

---

<sub>There is a similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95520/allow-improve-for-tag-wiki-edit-suggestions), but they are asking why they can't improve edits, only approve them (insufficient Rep). This question is about the site improperly offering reviewers the choice to improve, then denying the reviewer the ability to do so.</sub>

Comment: Improving does require full editing privileges. You would see that button if it was a non-wiki edit, and it would immediately approve the edit and make the additional changes. Since you don't have full editing privileges for tag wikis, you cannot do the second part of that process, and thus the improve option is not available for them. Are you saying the instructions for improve still appear on the page when the option is not available? If so, I'd say that's a bug.

Comment: @animuson Yes, the instructions are as I showed in the question: "Approve, reject, or **improve** edits suggested by users." Yet, the button for improve (correctly, it seems) is unavailable.